# Spring Boot Micrometer Influxdb custom data insert

Tags: spring-boot, influxdb, spring-boot-actuator

I have a `Spring Boot Application` which consumes data from `kafka` topic. I am using `Micrometer` and `Influxdb` for monitoring purpose. I read in documentation that, By adding `micrometer-registry-influx` we automatically enable exporting data to `InfluxDB`. I have some below questions on this -

What kind of data micrometer automatically adds to InfluxDB?

Can we add custom data to InfluxDB according to my application?

How can I publish custom or my application specific data to InfluxDB?

How can I disable adding default data to InfluxDB?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the documentation, the standard output set is described [here](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meters)

[Adding your own metrics](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_naming_meters)

[Metrics filter](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meter_filters) (here you can exclude standard metrics accordingly)

Comment: Hi @ RoyalGoose, thank you for the information. Can you please also provide any full example of micrometer with influxdb and grafana if available.